# How to use Woocommerce Api's using JWT token in Laravel?

Tags: wordpress, laravel, woocommerce

I am using Woocommerce for getting data in Laravel. I am using the package:

https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php

Now I am using consumer key and consumer secret for getting data. **But now requirement has been change. Now i want to get API's data using JWT Auth token.** This time I am creating object as,

```
 $this->client = new Client(
           Cookie::get('site_url'),
           Cookie::get('key'),
           Cookie::get('secret'),
            [
                'timeout' => 120,
                'version' => config('woocommerce.api_version'),
            ]
        );
```

And then call method to get, post, etc.

```
$this->client->get($endpoint, $parameters);
```

But I want to pass the JWT token to get data.

Comment: what is Client here guzzleclient?

Comment: I am using this use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

Comment: I have the see this `Automattic\WooCommerce\Client` before helping, share a github link to the package, most probably it is internally using guzzle, as the syntax is similar to guzzle

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php I am using this one

Comment: you have your jwt token with yourself & you want to send that jwt token to verify & get data?

Comment: Yes. I want to send token and get data

Comment: looking at the package, it is tailor made to handle requests via customer_id & customer_secret (see [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php/blob/master/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php#L248)), so use the Request class of it directly & pass a Auhorization header to it directly yourself, it will make work for you